# How to create snackbars in vuetify 3?

Tags: vue.js, migration, vuetify.js, css-transitions, snackbar

I want to create snackbars as shown in this example (vuetify 2). My question is how can i do it in vuetify 3.

https://codepen.io/scp-nm/pen/LYpBeoe?editors=1010

[image: Vuetify 2 snackbar examples]

App.vue

```
<v-snackbar
  v-model="snackbar.visible"
  auto-height
  :color="snackbar.color"
  :multi-line="snackbar.mode === 'multi-line'"
  :timeout="snackbar.timeout"
  :top="snackbar.position === 'top'"
>
  <v-layout align-center pr-4>
    <v-icon class="pr-3" dark large>{{ snackbar.icon }}</v-icon>
    <v-layout column>
      <div>
        <strong>{{ snackbar.title }}</strong>
      </div>
      <div>{{ snackbar.text }}</div>
    </v-layout>
  </v-layout>
  <v-btn
    v-if="snackbar.timeout === 0"
    icon
    @click="snackbar.visible = false"
  >
    <v-icon>clear</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-snackbar>
```

When i convert the vue 2 code to vue 3, transitions does not work and vuetify 3 api not clear as i expected.

[Here is my code workspace](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/olomadev/testvuetify/main?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clf58w81l000cg3ivgi8zeb2w%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.vue%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252Fmain.js%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clfjgz9lu02w93n6lz3x6w60e%2522%253A%257B%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clfjgzqu8034w3n6l0r2sq15y%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clfjgz9lu02w83n6l8fj7cihf%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clfjgz9lu02w93n6lz3x6w60e%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clfjgz9lu02w93n6lz3x6w60e%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clfjgz9lu02w93n6lz3x6w60e%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D)

Comment: your sandbox doesn't seem to work, I get Vuetify Hello World screen only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned your sandbox isn't working so probably easier just share a quick example as I completely understand where you are with the migration but this fairly simple example will set you on your way!

**Template:**

```
<v-snackbar
  :timeout="timeout"
  v-model="show"
>
  {{ message }}
    <template
      v-slot:actions
    >
      <v-btn
        variant="text"
        @click="show=false"
      >
        Close
      </v-btn>
    </template>
</v-snackbar>
```

**Script:**

```
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      message: '',
      timeout: 3000,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSnackbar() {
      this.message = 'This is a snackbar!'
      this.show = true;
    },
  }
```

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/KKxGYXx/6f787eea03f27fcf290b4b938cbd11c5

**UPDATE:**
Transitions don't appear to work, maybe this WIP (like a lot of stuff!).
You can fudged this yourself with a bit of custom CSS. I've updated the Codepen, it works but the CSS isn't particular nice!
You also need the `eager` prop to have the snackbar rendered.

```
<v-snackbar
  :timeout="timeout"
  v-model="show"
  :location="location"
  transition="slide-y-transition" // not working
  eager
>
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the transition effects ? There is a transition [property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-snackbar/#props-transition) in api. How can i use it. I want to it totaly  like this [https://codepen.io/scp-nm/pen/LYpBeoe?editors=1010](https://codepen.io/scp-nm/pen/LYpBeoe?editors=1010)

Comment: @ErsinGüvenç see update ^^^

Comment: Transition didn't work for me either. 
If it's WIP, it shouldn't be included in the API. It should at least have an indicator that it's WIP.